# Guidelines on structuring large racket project

Tags: racket

Is there any general guidelines (equivalent to [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) ) on how to structure large racket project ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is about structuring large Racket projects, however your example link [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) seems mainly to be about how to create a package. These aren't necessarily the same thing (although you might divide a large Racket program into different source directories, which could be "collections" or "packages"). Anyway, to address both parts:

1. **How to structure a large Racket project:** Asumu's answer provides a good link: [How to Program Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/index.html). In particular see [section 3, "Units of Code"](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Units_of_Code.html), which discusses *modules*. Also, one technique you will see in the source code of Racket itself, is that a module may exist solely to `require` functions from others and `provide` them -- to "re-provide". In other words you can use modules like this to chunk up other modules and selectively expose them as a "layer" in your structure. Furthermore, Racket has a *class* system if that fits your problem domain, and *generics* if you have some sort of "interface" or "protocol" strategy. And more. Really, there a many, many techniques available in Racket to structure a large project.
2. **How to make Racket packages:** This is an interesting time to ask. Historically Racket has used something called Planet as a package manager. More recently, it has a new package system. Although not yet officially out of beta, many people are already using it for real work. The current documentation for that, although in a different style than the Go doc, is [Package Management in Racket Beta)](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/).

You asked for general guidelines, which is a bit open-ended. If you have any specific choices you're weighing for how to structure a large project, perhaps you could ask about those one by one to get crisper answers?

Answer (score 7):

There is a Racket style guide called [How to Program Racket](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/) that will ship in the documentation of a future version of Racket. You can read it at the link I posted or in the bundled docs if you build the [git version](https://github.com/plt/racket) of Racket.